# Should this new MacBook Pro be returned?

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, graphics

I ordered the base model MacBook Pro 13" with upgraded SSD and RAM about one week ago. I was starting to feel I maybe bought something of a lemon—seeing things like a spontaneous shutdown, a Safari keyboard shortcut only intermittently working, mute apparently toggling itself, occasional app freezes, etc.—but couldn't find any pattern to make me believe it might not be coincidental software issues, or possibly from an external HDD working hard.

Now Mail is consistently showing unusual graphical behaviour in the message list: [Mail graphical glitch (video)](https://www.qetuodesigns.com/mail_glitch.mov). (Note: Empty rectangles added to censor personal data; they are not part of the problem.)

As I move about the message list with the arrow keys, the list glitches in strange ways. This happened in another folder as well. I can't find anyone else talking about this online, so I'm looking for opinions. Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider returning it back to Apple?

Comment: If this is new, then I would recommend to return it rather than fixing it. Fixation might be temporary and you never know it will appear back again. So, please get the new replacement on it as you have brought it lately.

Comment: Assuming this is a brand new OS installation, and you haven't installed out-of-date or incompatible software that might be affecting performance, then I would certainly take it to an Apple Store and get an opinion. Occasionally (out of the millions of units made at the factory), a duff machine will slip through quality control.

Comment: Return it ASAP.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Udhy benwiggy IconDaemon: Thank you for the chorus of "return it" suggestions—I bit the bullet and did just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should consider returning it back to Apple and get a refund:

- [Returns & Refunds](https://www.apple.com/shop/help/returns_refund)

> - You have 14 calendar days to return an item from the date you received it.
> - Only items that have been purchased directly from Apple, either online or at an Apple Retail Store, can be returned to Apple. Apple products purchased through other retailers must be returned in accordance with their respective returns and refunds policy.